# eclipse(4.6 NEON)でtomcatのトラアイコンが表示されません

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

初歩的な質問で恐縮なのですが、プラグインダウンロード後のトラアイコンの表示ができません。

この度eclipseのtomcatプラグイン（tomcatPluginV331.zip ）をダウンロードし、
「com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.1.jar」をeclipseのpluginsフォルダ内に配置しました。

その後コマンドプロンプトからeclipse.exeのあるディレクトリにてeclipse -cleanでeclipseを起動し、
「ウィンドウ」→「パースペクティブ」→「パースペクティブのカスタマイズ」→「アクション・セット可用性」を
見るも、tomcatのチェック項目がなく、トラアイコンの表示ができずにいます。

ちなみに、eclipseはver4.6(NEON)のJava FullEdition(32bit)でPCはWindows7(32bit)です。
ネットで色々と検索をかけるも上記のチェック項目自体が無いという事例がありませんでした。

ささいなことでも構いませんので、もし何かお気づきの点がありましたらご教授頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: yukihaneさん補足ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(対応としては既に書かれている手順で問題無いと考えますが、若干不正確かなと思いましたので補足します。)

---

プラグインのインストール方法が変わったわけではなく、インストール方法の選択肢が増えた、というのが正確ですね。
`plugins`ディレクトリにファイルを配置する方法が使用できなくなったわけではありません。

ではなぜ質問文記載の手順でプラグインが認識されなかったかというと、単純にそのプラグイン [Sysdeo Tomcat Plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) がNeonに対応していない、というだけですね。

マーケットプレイスから入手できる[Eclipse Tomcat Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-tomcat-plugin) は

> This project is the successor of the original Sysdeo Tomcat Plugin.
>   (中略)
>   Eclipse Versions: 
>   Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1), Oxygen (4.7)

とある通り、オリジナル版をフォークし、新しいEclipseに対応させたものですので今後はこちらを用いれば良いでしょう。

参考:

- [Sysdeo Tomcat plugin not working in Eclipse Luna - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791317/4506703)

Answer (score 1):

質問を立てておいて恐縮なのですが、その後自己解決できました。
もし同じ境遇で立ち止まった方がいましたら参考にしてください。

まず、eclipse ver.4.6 NEONではプラグイン用のダウンロードの仕方が従来と異なるようです。

アプリケーション内の「ヘルプ」→「Eclipseマーケットプレース」より「tomcat」を検索、
「Eclipse Tomcat Plugin 9.1.2」というネコのマークのプラグインがあるので、それをダウンロード。

少し待ってダウンロードが完了後、アプリを再起動する必要がありますと出るので再起動し、
無事メニューバーにトラアイコンが追加されました。
（パースペクティブのカスタマイズの方でもtomcatのチェック項目が追加されていました）

ネットでもまだ情報があまり出回っていないみたいなので、割と新しい仕様なのかもしれません。
お騒がせしました。。